# Sitecore - Is this an 'internal' site?

Tags: sitecore

Is there an easy way to determine if a site is one of Sitecore's own sites?

Basically, what I'm looking for is shorthand for:

```cs
var sitenames = new string[] {"admin","shell","login","service"}; // etc.

if(!sitenames.Contains(Sitecore.Context.Site.Name))
    //do stuff
```

I don't see anything in the `SiteContext` or `SiteInfo` classes that look helpful for this.

I'm quite happy to write this functionality myself. I just want to make sure it's not already hidden away somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the Site definitions in the web.config all Sitecore internal things have the domain property set to Sitecore.

So basically something like this:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Domain != Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain.GetDomain("sitecore"))
{
    // [Do stuff here]
}
```

Comment: but Site:modules_website's domain name is 'extranet'. how would that be ignored ? correct me if iam wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Off the back of @Trayek's answer I wrote this extension method, which works nicely.

```cs
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class SiteContextExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsInternal(this SiteContext siteContext)
        {
            return siteContext.Domain.Name == "sitecore";
        }
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```cs
if(!Sitecore.Context.Site.IsInternal())
    // Do stuff
```